# Is there any Android device with resolution 640x960?

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

I'm not sure if this is the best place for this question, if not please point me the right one!

I am scaling my app for multiple resolutions and I've come across this two pages

Look on [Scren Sizes and densities](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), the chart says 17% of the devices are normal/xhdpi, also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing), in the Table 3 it says that normal/xhdpi is 640x960.

I know this is the Iphone resolution, running searches on google and gsmarena and I can only find iPhones and some android devices yet to be released.

So my question is among tablets and phones, already in the market, is there any android device with this resolution? If not, why is that resolution in that table?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So according to the answers there are no devices with that resolution, but if there are no android devices with that resolution, which ones fit in those 17% with normal size and xhdpi? Why is that even on the chart?

Comment: This will be closed on Stack Overflow in a heartbeat.

Comment: Have a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/list-of-devices-with-screen-parameters

Comment: I didn't put on Stack Overflow because it will be closed before someone can reply. Thank you for the list, it'll do it for now! I'm still curious on that detail though, any suggestions about other places where I can ask would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal/xhdpi is the bucket that the Galaxy Nexus and all other 720p (1280x720) normal sized phones fall into.  720p has become a popular resolution for high end Android phones which is why you see 17% in that bucket.  The 960x640 resolution you see listed is just the minimum resolution to be considered xhdpi with a normal size screen.  It doesn't necessarily mean that there are phones with that resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how everything(text,images...) will be scaled on base of mdpi for xhdpi if 720p is in normal/xhdpi?

Comment: 720p is in normal/xhdpi but it's also in other buckets depending on the size of the screen.  For instance, the Nexus 7 is 720p but it's not normal/xhdpi.  You have to take your screen size into consideration and not just the resolution.  This is why Google recommends not using the small/normal/large/xlarge buckets and instead using sw360dp/sw480dp/sw600dp/sw720dp buckets.

Answer (score 2):

Current resolutions in Arc/Neo/Pro/Play & S2 are good... higher resolution will surely increase the sharpness of images and the whole UI duo to the higher ppi but it will have negative impacts too 
1- small difference in battery life... this is small enough to just ignore 
2- lower performance in 3D games and UI rendering...

the iPhone 4 GPU it self ( SGX 535 ) is slower than the  Adreno 205, and it also uses higher resolution this is why 3D games dev. have to sacrifice quality to have playable fps...

currently the fastest GPU is SGX 540 ( used for example in OMAP 4430, in the heart of Optimus 3D )... and Tegra 2 which is a little bit slower than SGX 540.. and btw Tegra 2 by it self is a whole SoC and not just a GPU.. but it uses nV own GPU and no one else is using it.. and they cost more than Adreno 205 based SoC ( this what makes Adreno 205 more mainstream in the high-end )... but both of these GPU's are still not powerful enough to give 30 - 40 fps in high resolution like 960x640

so next year when the new or newer GPU's becomes mainstream and cost same as what todays Adreno 205, SGX 540 cost's then we may see higher resolution that can be used without sacrificing performance... but don't expect a direct jump between 854x480 to 960x640, there's a hell a lot of pixels there to compute  and screen panel makers tend to have a control hand here too... the close one is **Atrix** which has **960x540** ( 100px less in width than iPhone 4 ) and it uses Tegra 2.

*EDIT :* Just found this! **Sharp IS03** has a **960x640 resolution**. But, unfortunately it has been released only in Japan.
Check these links for more info on it : [link1](http://phandroid.com/2010/10/04/retina-display-comes-to-android-with-sharp-iso3/) , [link2](http://androidmixer.com/sharp-iso3-android-phone-release-date-and-specs/), [link3](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2631&c=sharp_is03).

Comment: There is a nice piece of information there, I didn't know that. But still, if there are no phones with that, what other phones fit in the category of normal size/xhdpi?

Comment: Motorola Atrix is the closest thing you have right now. 960x540. You can go for that.

Comment: Update : Sharp IS03 has 960x640. Check the edit in my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of obscure, but this seems to count:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meizu_M9

...unless you're looking for *Western* phones. Never seen one in real life, though. My own personal big list of wacky Android devices doesn't show any 640x960 screens, but I have encountered a 540x960 one.

Comment: We can find a couple 540x960, that Meizu certainly fits it but I doubt it reaches 17% of the android devices in the market. It has to be something else! I've edited my question!

Comment: ...you are aware that you can get xhdpi devices which aren't 640x960? Any screen size with a resolution of about 320dpi will count. I'd reckon that a normal sized screen at 540x960 is probably close enough to be xhdpi. The table you link to shows *representative* screen sizes, not definitive ones.

Comment: Yes I am what I need is me to a list, an article, or a couple of devices that fit in that category. I want to know what kind of devices fit in those 17%. Are they phones? Tablets? Big? Small?

Comment: I'm sorry, but at this point I can't answer your question because I don't know what your question actually is any more! You may want to consider doing a major edit to clarify what it is you want to know...